# Remove "_months" in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

`df = {'name' : ['maman','tata','papa','uncle'], 'date' : ['6_months','4_months','2_months', '2_months'], 'amount' : [2000 , 600 , 500 , 100 ]}` 
How can i please remove the "_months" and just keep the numbers in the columns

Comment: Suggestion: `df["date"] = df["date"].str.rstrip("_months").astype(int)`, but other options are possible

Comment: Assuming you construct a dataframe from this dict, i.e., `df = pd.DataFrame(df)`, try `df["date"].str.replace("_months", "").astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = {'name' : ['maman','tata','papa','uncle'], 'date' : ['6_months','4_months','2_months', '2_months'], 'amount' : [2000 , 600 , 500 , 100 ]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df['date'] = [int(x.split("_")[0]) for x in df['date']]   #It is store as an int
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    name  date  amount
0  maman     6    2000
1   tata     4     600
2   papa     2     500
3  uncle     2     100
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you didnt put any code that you used it seems like your df is saved in a dict so i used some simple python looping and dict actions:

```
df = {'name' : ['maman','tata','papa','uncle'], 'date' : ['6_months','4_months','2_months', '2_months'], 'amount' : [2000 , 600 , 500 , 100 ]}

fixed_dates = []
for value in df['date']:
    fixed_dates.append(value.split('_')[0])
        
print(fixed_dates)
df['date'] = fixed_dates
print(df)
```